# How to convert nested list of lists into a list of tuples in python 3.3?

Tags: python, list, tuples, nested-lists, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a nested list of lists into a list of tuples in Python 3.3. However, it seems that I don't have the logic to do that.

The input looks as below:

```
>>> nested_lst = [['tom', 'cat'], ['jerry', 'mouse'], ['spark', 'dog']]
```

And the desired ouptput should look as exactly as follows:

```
nested_lst_of_tuples = [('tom', 'cat'), ('jerry', 'mouse'), ('spark', 'dog')]
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
nested_lst_of_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in nested_lst]
```

Demo:

```
>>> nested_lst = [['tom', 'cat'], ['jerry', 'mouse'], ['spark', 'dog']]
>>> [tuple(l) for l in nested_lst]
[('tom', 'cat'), ('jerry', 'mouse'), ('spark', 'dog')]
```

Comment: What if the level of nesting for each item is unknown? Well, Mr. Pieters already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27050037/4465708) :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> list(map(tuple, [['tom', 'cat'], ['jerry', 'mouse'], ['spark', 'dog']]))
[('tom', 'cat'), ('jerry', 'mouse'), ('spark', 'dog')]
```

This is equivalent to a list comprehension, except that `map` returns a generator instead of a list.

Answer (score 7):

```
[tuple(l) for l in nested_lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

I used list comprehension as a solution , below is my style

```
nested_lst = [['tom', 'cat'], ['jerry', 'mouse'], ['spark', 'dog']]

nested_new_list =[(i,j) for i,j in nested_lst]

print(nested_new_list)

output : [('tom', 'cat'), ('jerry', 'mouse'), ('spark', 'dog')]
```