# Convert a mixed nested list to a nested tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

If I have

```
easy_nested_list = [['foo', 'bar'], ['foofoo', 'barbar']]
```

and would like to have

```
(('foo', 'bar'), ('foofoo', 'barbar'))
```

I can do

```
tuple(tuple(i) for i in easy_nested_list)
```

but if I have

```
mixed_nested_list = [['foo', 'bar'], ['foofoo', ['foo', 'bar']],'some', 2, 3]
```

and would like to build a tuple out of this, I don't know how to start.

It would be nice to get:

```
(('foo', 'bar'), ('foofoo', ('foo', 'bar')), 'some', 2, 3)
```

The first problem is that Python turns my string into a tuple for each character. The second thing is I get

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Convert recursively, and test for lists:

```
def to_tuple(lst):
    return tuple(to_tuple(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in lst)
```

This produces a tuple for a given list, but converts any nested `list` objects using a recursive call.

Demo:

```
>>> def to_tuple(lst):
...     return tuple(to_tuple(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in lst)
... 
>>> mixed_nested_list = [['foo', 'bar'], ['foofoo', ['foo', 'bar']],'some', 2, 3]
>>> to_tuple(mixed_nested_list)
(('foo', 'bar'), ('foofoo', ('foo', 'bar')), 'some', 2, 3)
```