# Check if 2d array exists in 3d array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an 3d array with shape `(1000, 12, 30)`, and I have a list of 2d array's of shape `(12, 30)`, what I want to do is check if these 2d arrays exist in the 3d array. Is there a simple way in Python to do this? I tried keyword `in` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The solution here should apply to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100242/python-numpy-first-occurrence-of-subarray#20689091. Marking duplicate

Comment: Those questions are not the same.

Comment: The solutions apply to this case. Adjust the rolling window accordingly

Comment: It doesn't apply. Questions that are a duplicate should be marked as a duplicate, those are not the same questions. I don't understand why you would mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I have retracted the flag though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way in `numpy` , you can do with `np.all`

```
a = np.random.rand(3, 1, 2)
b = a[1][0]
np.all(np.all(a == b, 1), 1)
Out[612]: array([False,  True, False])
```

Solution from bnaecker

```
np.all(a == b, axis=(1, 2))
```

If only want to check exit or not

```
np.any(np.all(a == b, axis=(1, 2)))
```

Comment: Or better yet, `np.all(a == b, axis=(1,2))`.

Comment: @Wen I see! thanks for this. I'm still not sure how this would work if the depth is 30 like what I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff Check out NumPy's [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). `b` in this case will be broadcast (replicated) along the first dimension to match `a`. Then the `axis` arguments to `np.all` reduce that along the last two dimensions, leaving a boolean array of shape `(30,)` with `True` at indices `i` where `a[i] == b`.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff Also note, that you might need to use `np.allclose()` rather than `np.all()` if you're dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: @bnaecker I understand. But I want to return True only if the complete (12, 30) array exist in the (1000, 12, 30). I think the solution mentioned above checks each single value in the 30 lists and outputs a boolean for each?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff add np.any `np.any(np.all(a == b, axis=(1,2)))
`

Comment: @Wen This is great! Could you add this into your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fast method (previously [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397704/find-index-given-multiple-values-of-array-with-numpy/49400557#49400557) [by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988038/find-boolean-mask-by-pattern/49002944#49002944) @DanielF as well [as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/4427777) @jaime and others, no doubt) that uses a trick to benefit from short-circuiting: view-cast template-sized blocks to single elements of dtype `void`. When comparing two such blocks numpy stops after the first difference, yielding a huge speed advantage.

```
>>> def in_(data, template):
...     dv = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1).view(f'V{data.dtype.itemsize*np.prod(data.shape[1:])}').ravel()
...     tv = template.ravel().view(f'V{template.dtype.itemsize*template.size}').reshape(())
...     return (dv==tv).any()
```

Example:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 12, 30))
>>> check = a[np.random.randint(0, 1000, (10,))]
>>> check += np.random.random(check.shape) < 0.001    
>>>
>>> [in_(a, c) for c in check]
[True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False]
# compare to other method
>>> (a==check[:, None]).all((-1,-2)).any(-1)
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False])
```

Gives same result as "direct" numpy approach, but is almost 20x faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100)
>>> 
>>> timeit("(a==check[:, None]).all((-1,-2)).any(-1)", **kwds)
0.4793281531892717
>>> timeit("[in_(a, c) for c in check]", **kwds)
0.026218891143798828
```

Comment: I was hoping someone would who was better at actual coding would eventually improve my old `vview` code.  Once you have the void view couldn't you just use `np.in1d` though?

Comment: @DanielF You are right, that should be even faster. Could you give me a pointer to your post so I can properly credit you?

Comment: @DanielF Strange, I tried with `in1d` or rather the new `isin` and it is 10x slower. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: I've given answers with it a few times: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397704/find-index-given-multiple-values-of-array-with-numpy/49400557#49400557) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988038/find-boolean-mask-by-pattern/49002944#49002944) most recently.  But the original idea came from @jaime [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973510/4427777)

Answer (score 2):

### Numpy

Given

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 2, 2)
lst = [
    np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2),
    np.arange(4, 8).reshape(2, 2)
]

print(a, *lst, sep='\n{}\n'.format('-' * 20))

[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]]

 [[ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]]

 [[ 8  9]
  [10 11]]]
--------------------
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
--------------------
[[4 5]
 [6 7]]
```

Notice that `lst` is a list of arrays as per OP.  I'll make that a 3d array `b`  below.

Use broadcasting.  Using the broadcasting rules.  I want the dimensions of `a` as `(1, 3, 2, 2)` and `b` as `(2, 1, 2, 2)`.

```
b = np.array(lst)
x, *y = b.shape
c = np.equal(
    a.reshape(1, *a.shape),
    np.array(lst).reshape(x, 1, *y)
)
```

I'll use `all` to produce a `(2, 3)` array of truth values and `np.where` to find out which among the `a` and `b` sub-arrays are actually equal.

```
i, j = np.where(c.all((-2, -1)))
```

This is just a verification that we achieved what we were after.  We are supposed to observe that for each paired `i` and `j` values, the sub-arrays are actually the same.

```
for t in zip(i, j):
    print(a[t[0]], b[t[1]], sep='\n\n')
    print('------')

[[0 1]
 [2 3]]

[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
------
[[4 5]
 [6 7]]

[[4 5]
 [6 7]]
------
```

---

### `in`

However, to complete OP's thought on using `in`

```
a_ = a.tolist()
list(filter(lambda x: x.tolist() in a_, lst))

[array([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]), array([[4, 5],
        [6, 7]])]
```