# Converting nested tuple into nested list in python

Tags: python, list, collections, tuples

I have nested tuple like below wanted to convert into nested list in the format mentioned

Input:

```
T = [('id','1'),('name','Mike'),('Adrs','Tor')]
```

Output:

```
L = [['id','1'],['name','Mike'],['Adrs','Tor']]
```

Comment: `L.append(list(item))`?

Comment: Hi , It errors out as list object is not callable.

Comment: It works for me at least. What error are you receiving excactly?

Comment: that error means that probably you have used name `list` and overriden the built-in function `list()`. Don't use `list` as variable name.

Comment: Same 'TypeError "list' object is not callable

Comment: Yes actually same was the reason. I was trying for long. Thanks !

Comment: Related (opposite direction, though): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938276/how-to-convert-nested-list-of-lists-into-a-list-of-tuples-in-python-3-3

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> spam = [('id','1'),('name','Mike'),('Adrs','Tor')]
>>> eggs = [list(item) for item in spam]
>>> eggs
[['id', '1'], ['name', 'Mike'], ['Adrs', 'Tor']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could unpack each separate tuple and then append it

```
L = []

for item in T:
    a, b = item
    L.append([a,b])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [('id','1'),('name','Mike')]
m = [[], []]
for i in range(len(l)):
    m[i] = [l[i][0], l[i][1]]
print(m)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.